# changing slider value as List item value in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

I have this page which load a list of student and them degrees.

first i have this class :

```
class MyList {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final double degree;
  MyList(this.id, this.name, this.degree);
}
```

then i have this page :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './class.dart';
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List newList = [];
    MyList newlist1 = MyList(1, 'sar', 25.0);
    newList.add(newlist1);
    MyList newlist2 = MyList(2, 'Moh', 10.0);
    newList.add(newlist2);
    MyList newlist3 = MyList(3, 'John', 12.0);
    newList.add(newlist3);
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
        double _value = newList[index].degree;
        return Column(
          children: [
            Text(newList[index].id.toString()),
            Text(newList[index].name),
            Slider(
                value: _value,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                divisions: 5,
                label: _value.round().toString(),
                onChanged: (double value) {
                  setState(() => _value = value);
                }),
          ],
        );
      },
      itemCount: newList.length,
    ));
  }
}
```

That i want to do is when i moving the range slider two things:

1- change the value of slider to the new value.

2- update new degree value in the list.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this code, you need to have some change:

1. in the MyList class, you should change degree variable to not
   final. (final variable can not change after first assign.)
2. define of newList must go out of build widget. (build widget in
   statefull class rebuild in every state call)
3. change your Slider divisions to 100.
4. in setState call, should change newList[index].degree value

your code should be like this:

```
class MyList {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  double degree;
  MyList(this.id, this.name, this.degree);
}

List _getNewList(){
  List newList = [];
  MyList newlist1 = MyList(1, 'sar', 25.0);
  newList.add(newlist1);
  MyList newlist2 = MyList(2, 'Moh', 10.0);
  newList.add(newlist2);
  MyList newlist3 = MyList(3, 'John', 12.0);
  newList.add(newlist3);

  return newList;
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  List _newList = _getNewList();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            double _value = _newList[index].degree;
            return Column(
              children: [
                Text(_newList[index].id.toString()),
                Text(_newList[index].name),
                Slider(
                    value: _value,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    divisions: 100,
                    label: _value.round().toString(),
                    onChanged: (double value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _value = value;
                        _newList[index].degree = value;
                      });
                    }),
              ],
            );
          },
          itemCount: _newList.length,
        ));
  }
}
```